# Boxplot on matplotlib with rows according if column X has a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

I have a table with 501 column. The first column basically has a value of either -1 or 1. This value is based somehow on the other 500. I'm trying to find the relationship and in order to do that will need some visualization.

Now there are more than 1000 rows and i decided to do a box plot. I want to take the first column and plot six random boxplots each for each values (-1 and 1)

So the plot is to search the first column, if value is -1 - take the other column and plot a boxplot of their values. But since the values are in a row that is a bit f problem. Also getting it to pick 6 random values at both -1 nd 1 is too. I recon i have to create a new list or dataframe with the 6 values for each (-1 & 1) but how to do that

Photo attached 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5Gnx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {
    'a': pd.Series(np.random.choice([1, -1], size=10)),
    'b': pd.Series(np.random.randn(10)),
    'c': pd.Series(np.random.randn(10))
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# plot for first column when value is 1
df[df.a == 1].sample(3).T.iloc[1:].boxplot()

# plot for first column when value is -11
df[df.a == -1].sample(3).T.iloc[1:].boxplot()
```

Explanation:

Get rows where first value is equal to `1`

```
df[df.a == 1]
```

Get random 3 row from filtered ones

```
df[df.a == -1].sample(3)
```

Throw out first colum (that with ones) and transpose the DataFrame (this way your box plots will be plotted for each row instead of columns)

```
df[df.a == -1].sample(3).T.iloc[1:]
```

Finally plot the boxplot

```
df[df.a == -1].sample(3).T.iloc[1:].boxplot()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. To clarify: you had ['b', 'c'] since i have 500 entries I omitted that part and plotted the boxplot. How can i confirm it used all the data from the 500 entries or is some?

Comment: @Kabayomi just check by using `shape` like so: `df[df.a == 1].sample(3).T.iloc[1:].shape` it should output something like `(500, <number of_rows>)`.
If my answer helped you, please accept it.